# How to increase memory_limit in php.ini file from cli?

Tags: php

I tried to install a package using this command on magemojo server :
**composer require cweagans/composer-patches**.
But it is giving me below error

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223**

Can anyone provide me with any solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the below in the start of the php script to change the memory limit for the specific php script

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit', '3072M');

echo "mem_limit:";

echo ini_get('memory_limit')


?>
```

You can also change  the setting  "memory_limit" in php.ini   as below

memory_limit = 3072M

Comment: How would you use this when you're installing a package using composer (which seem to be when they get the error) in CLI? That memory limit you set would only be set during that very script.

Comment: Thankyou this solved my problem